# SQL Row not printing correct value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am fairly new to SQL statements and I am trying to print units sold from a database. Under the units sold column it will not print the number it will just print "Units Sold". Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
SELECT brand_name, brand_type, Round(avgprice,2) AS "Average Price", "Units Sold"
FROM lgbrand b 
JOIN (
   SELECT brand_id, Avg(prod_price) AS avgprice
   FROM lgproduct
   GROUP BY brand_id
) sub1 ON b.brand_id = sub1.brand_id
JOIN (
   SELECT brand_id, Sum(line_qty) AS "Units Sold" 
   FROM lgproduct p 
   JOIN lgline l ON p.prod_sku = l.prod_sku
   GROUP BY brand_id
) sub2 ON b.brand_id = sub2.brand_id

ORDER BY brand_name;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT brand_name, brand_type, Round(avgprice,2) AS "Average Price",  Units_Sold
FROM lgbrand b 
JOIN (
   SELECT brand_id, Avg(prod_price) AS avgprice
   FROM lgproduct
   GROUP BY brand_id
) sub1 ON b.brand_id = sub1.brand_id
JOIN (
   SELECT brand_id, Sum(line_qty) AS Units_Sold
   FROM lgproduct p 
   JOIN lgline l ON p.prod_sku = l.prod_sku
   GROUP BY brand_id
) sub2 ON b.brand_id = sub2.brand_id

ORDER BY brand_name;
```

Comment: It got the column to not say units sold anymore, but the values are not correct, first one is suppose to be 3753 and first one with that code is 6062

Comment: @RyanBlanchard you would have to explain a lot more about your data model sample values and expected results before I could help you with that.